# How does rails get http header data from CloudFlare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudflare

Hope it won't take too much time. I am very new to RoR. Here is the question: How can I get HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY from my rails app if my cloudflare has been configured correctly?

I know it is very naive. But pls help me out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should be able to use:

```
request.headers["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]
```

Comment: Yes indeed. But strange thing is that when I try "binding.pry" in my view page, and there is no such key in the request hash. Maybe it's not visible in my local development environment, so I didn't notice it. Thanks very much.

Comment: You won't be able to see this in your dev environment, because CloudFlare is not proxying your requests.

Comment: Thanks! I was using just 
headers["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"] which must be the response headers.